# Rotate animation from centre of view not working

Tags: android, pivot, center, rotateanimation

I want to make a rotate animation for my view but in both sides (java and xml) I cant find any way to rotate view from it's centre

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="500"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:repeatCount="infinite"
android:repeatMode="reverse"
android:toDegrees="180" />
```

and this:

```
RotateAnimation animation = new RotateAnimation(0,180,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f);
```

both of them rotate view from its corner

please help me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like you try rotate all layout, not view. That you need.
worked code

```
View view = findViewById( R.id.image );
aRotate = new RotateAnimation(fStartAngle, fEndAngle,
          Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

aRotate.setStartOffset(0);
aRotate.setDuration(2000);
aRotate.setFillAfter(true);
aRotate.setInterpolator(context, android.R.anim.decelerate_interpolator);

view.startAnimation(aRotate);
```

Comment: Thank you! I was having trouble using `view.setAnimation` instead of `view.startAnimation`.